# Undefined reference to libusb_get_parent() - compiling freenect

Tags: makefile, kinect

I'd want to install some libraries in order to connect a Kinect 360 in a Raspberry following this link: http://www.kdab.com/setting-up-kinect-for-programming-in-linux-part-1/

First, I checked this on Ubuntu and all was fine.
However, when I want to build libfreenect (with make) this error is shown:

```
../lib/libfreenect.so.0.5.2: undefined reference to 'lisusb_get_parent'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm new on Raspberry and I don't know how to fix this.

Any help is appreciated!! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, starting from a fresh install of Raspbian 2015-02-16.  Apparently (based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154982/tell-linux-to-use-latest-libusbx-i-have-downloaded)), the version of libusb you get with apt-get is old.  My workaround, based on recommendations from that link and elsewhere, is to build libusb from the more recent sources and convince libfreenect to use that:

Grab the packages you'll need to compile libusb and libfreenect:

```
sudo apt-get install git cmake build-essential
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
```

Remove the existing libusb, if it's there:

```
sudo apt-get remove libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

Grab the sources for libusb-1.0.18:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/files/libusb-1.0/libusb-1.0.18/libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2
tar -xvf libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2
```

Build and install the updated libusb:

```
cd libusb-1.0.18/
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static
make
sudo make install
```

Ugly hack to convince libfreenect to use the new libusb library:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so
```

Then you should be able to build libfreenect.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks KDeus!

Comment: KDeus!!.. Awesome .. saved a lot of time for me :).

Comment: Thanks, but I am now getting this error: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h` I may be missing something, but do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Lucas, that doesn't look like an error...it looks like a strange command attempting to add a header file to the linker path for some reason.  Could you provide more context?

Comment: To avoid the "ugly hack": `cmake -L .. -DLIBUSB_1_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so`

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so
```

when u r using x86_64 machine